# Get MethodInfo for a lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, lambda

I know I am asking the bizarre but just for kicks, is it possible to get the `MethodInfo` for a lambda expression?

I am after something like this:

`(Func<int, string>(i => i.ToString())).MethodInfo`

**UPDATE**
I want to get the method info regardless of whether the body of the lamda is a method call expression or not, i.e. regardless of what type of expression the body of the lambda is.

So, for e.g.

This might work.

```
var intExpression = Expression.Constant(2);
Expression<Func<int, Dog>> conversionExpression = i => Program.GetNewDog(i);

var convertExpression5 = Expression.ConvertChecked(intExpression, typeof(Dog), ((MethodCallExpression)(conversionExpression.Body)).Method);

class Program
{
  static Dog GetNewDog(int i)
  {
    return new Dog();
  }
}
```

But I want even this to work:

```
var intExpression = Expression.Constant(2);
Expression<Func<int, Dog>> conversionExpression = i => new Dog();

var convertExpression5 = Expression.ConvertChecked(intExpression, typeof(Dog), /*...???... */);
```

Comment: An expression does not have a method info. If you compile it, you can get the method info from the delegate.

Comment: I am not interested in creating an expression. I added the update in response to Timothy Shields' answer below. All I want is a methodInfo from a delegate. Possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are quite close :)

You can do something like this:

```
MethodInfo meth = (new Func<int, string>(i => i.ToString())).Method;
```

**Note:** This might have problems if you have multiple 'subscribers' to a delegate instance.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.method

Comment: But how could there be multiple subscribers to an anonymous method or a lambda? How would you even reference it at any place other than where it is declared?

Comment: You would have to first declare the delegate and then use `+=` to add additional subscribers. I agree, with anonymous delegates, this scenario is very unlikely. You can check for it though, or `Method` might be null in that case. Also be aware the delegate might have some context if the `Target` property is not null.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. You're saying if that `Func<T>` already has other methods in its invocation list, then just be careful, right?

Comment: You can use a cast instead of `new`.

Answer (score 11):

Using the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace, you can do the following.

```
Expression<Func<int, string>> expression = i => i.ToString();
MethodInfo method = ((MethodCallExpression)expression.Body).Method;
```

Comment: No, wait. That'll only work for this particular example. My bad. I should've clarified. I want it to work regardless of what the body of the lambda contains. This solution assumes that the body of the lambda is a method call expression, which is my fault, because I gave such an example.