# How to Get the parent Class name from a Func<T>?

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say I have a func, like the below one...

```
Func<ISession, IIncomingPacket, IControllerContext, Task>
```

How would I get the class that the func method belongs to?

Comment: If you mean you have a func instance and you want to tell which class method it is referencing to? `func.Method.DeclaringType` ?

Comment: just hover on it.

Comment: clicking F12 will move you the actual class of the function.

Comment: What if you have an anonymous method that does not have any class it belongs to?

Answer (score 1):

`Func` already has information about the declaring type: `myFunc.Method.DeclaringType`- see [Get MethodInfo for a lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792849/get-methodinfo-for-a-lambda-expression). Note so that really it is useless in most cases as frequently such function will be declared inline at the point of call - you may have to walk up through classes to find something useful.

```
Func<int, string> f = (i => i.ToString());
Console.Write(f.Method.DeclaringType.Name);
```

You can't get such information from `Func<...>` and really it is useless in most cases as frequently such function will be declared inline at the point of call.

Usually to get that information you'd use `Expression<...>` instead - see [How to get Method Name of Generic Func<T> passed into Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420404/how-to-get-method-name-of-generic-funct-passed-into-method) for an example.